# How to convert a numpy.ndarray type into a list?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, mat-file, tolist

I want to read a matfile in python and then export the data in a database. in order to do this I need to have the data type as list in python. I wrote the code below:

```
import scipy.io as si
import csv

a = si.loadmat('matfilename')
b = a['variable']                
list1=b.tolist()
```

The variable has 1 row and 15 columns. when I print `list1`, I get the answer below: (It is indeed a list, but a list that contains only one element. It means when I call list1[0], I get the same result.):

```
[[array(['A'], 
  dtype='<U13'), array(['B'], 
  dtype='<U14'), array(['C'], 
  dtype='<U6'), array(['D'], 
  dtype='<U4'), array(['E'], 
  dtype='<U10'), array(['F'], 
  dtype='<U13'), array(['G'], 
  dtype='<U11'), array(['H'], 
  dtype='<U9'), array(['I'], 
  dtype='<U16'), array(['J'], 
  dtype='<U18'), array(['K'], 
  dtype='<U16'), array(['L'], 
  dtype='<U16'), array(['M'], 
  dtype='<U16'), array(['N'], 
  dtype='<U14'), array(['O'], 
  dtype='<U13')]]
```

While the form that I expect is:

```
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O']
```

Does anyone know what the problem is?

Comment: Try: `b.astype(str).tolist()`? Or, `b.astype('<U8').tolist()`

Comment: Can you provide the `'matfilename'` file?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem unfortunately I cant provide it.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I get the error "ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence"

Comment: Can you provide a `print` of the `b` matrix  ?

Comment: "unfortunately I cant provide it" - We don't necessarily need the original file; but a two-line snippet with nonsense/anonymised data that have the same data types that your file has so that people can test your code go a long way toward quick and useful solutions.

Comment: @mozzafunk just added the b matrix above

Comment: @Amadan yes I understand but it is actually a very large data. one of ist variables is 1*15 cells and the data type in each field is string.

Comment: `loadmat` often uses object dtype arrays to reproduce the MATLAB cell and struct objects.  Only MATLAB matrices (numeric and string) become simple `numpy` arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my experience, that is just like MATLAB files are structured, only nested arrays.

You can create the list yourself:

```
>>> [x[0][0] for x in list1[0]]
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O']
```

Comment: nice, thanks. in order to have the whole strings I just had to change it a bit: [x[0][:] for x in list1[0]]

Comment: Yes, you will find different nesting levels. In the end you need to test how deep you need to index.